# How to passing functions to components?

Tags: reactjs

I am doing the implementation of list pagination through a custom hook. The `handleSetCurrentPage()` function gets the correct `number`, it uses `setCurrentPage(number)`. Consolelog `setCurrentPage(number)` showed `undefined`.
if you do all the same code only within one file (put everything in `ListOfItems`) it works fine.

Hook:

```
export const usePagination = (users = [], defaultPage = 1, amountPerPage = 10) => {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(defaultPage);
    const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState([]);
    const [amountOfPages, setAmountOfPages] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        updateUsers();
        updateAmountOfPages();
    }, []);

    const updateUsers = () => {
        const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * amountPerPage;
        const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - amountPerPage;
        const updatedUsers = users.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);
        setCurrentUsers(updatedUsers);
    };

    const updateAmountOfPages = () => {
        const updatedAmount = Math.ceil(users.length / amountPerPage);
        setAmountOfPages(updatedAmount);
    };

    return {
        setCurrentPage,
        amountOfPages,
        currentUsers,
    };
};
```

list of items:

```
export function ListOfItems() {
    const users = useSelector(state => state);
    const { setCurrentPage, currentUsers, amountOfPages } = usePagination(users);
    let {url} = useRouteMatch();

    let items = currentUsers.map(function (value, index) {
        return (
            <form key={index}>
                <div className="input-group">
                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                        <Link className="input-group-text" to={`${url}/${index}`}>
                            {value.name}, {index}
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {/*<form className="card">*/}
            {/*    <Search setSearch={setSearch} />*/}
            {/*</form>*/}
            <div>{items}</div>
            <div>
                <Pagination amountOfPages={amountOfPages} setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

pagination component:

```
const Pagination = ({amountOfPages, setCurrentPage}) => {
    const [pageNumbers, setPageNumbers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        calculatePageNumbers();
    }, [amountOfPages]);

    function calculatePageNumbers() {
        const updatedPageNumbers = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= amountOfPages; i++) {
            updatedPageNumbers.push(i);
        }
        setPageNumbers(updatedPageNumbers);
    }

    function handleSetCurrentPage(number) {
        console.log(number);
        return console.log(setCurrentPage(number));
    }

    return (
        <nav>
            <ul className="pagination">
                {pageNumbers.map(number => (
                    <li key={number} className="page-item">
                        <button
                            onClick={() => handleSetCurrentPage(number)}
                            type="button"
                            className="page-link"
                        >
                            {number}
                        </button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Pagination;
```

Comment: `Consolelog setCurrentPage(number) showed undefined` Are you expecting something else? react state setters return undefined.

Comment: @NicholasTower yes i expecting console.log my func not undefined. what will i do with this undefined?

Comment: `what will i do with this undefined?` nothing; that's why it seems so weird to me that you're trying to log it. If you want to log out the function itself, you can do `console.log(setCurrentPage)`, though i'm not sure what the purpose of that would be. Logging it out will not set the state.

Comment: @NicholasTower `Logging it out will not set the state`, yes, absolutely thats why i do this `console.log`, i can't get why setCurrentPage doesn't work? number in handleSetCurrentPage() dont set in state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 useEffect(() => {
        updateUsers();
        updateAmountOfPages();
    }, [currentPage]);
```

Comment: It's better to add some details around your answer.